# RallyApi in Java - Trying to return project hierarchy for a feature

Tags: rally

Given a Feature result set passed into this function, I am trying to traverse up the project hierarchy up to the subscription.  I can't I get  a null pointer on the projResponse =...  No even sure of the approach for this.

```
private static void getProjHierarchyForFeature(RallyRestApi restApi, QueryResponse featureSet,
        Time2Market time2market, Integer featureInSet) {

    String tempHierarchy = "";

    JsonArray tempFeatures = featureSet.getResults();
    //time2market.setProjectName(projectName);

    try {
        JsonObject obj1 = tempFeatures.get(featureInSet).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject proj = obj1.get("Project").getAsJsonObject();
        String url = proj.get("_ref").getAsString();
        QueryRequest projQuery = new QueryRequest(url);
        projQuery.setFetch(new Fetch("_ref", "_refObjectUUID", "_refObjectName"));
        QueryResponse projResponse = restApi.query(projQuery);

        if (projResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
            JsonArray tempProj = projResponse.getResults();

            // Here we have the project object, now process Parents...

            Boolean moreParents = true;

            while (moreParents) {
                QueryRequest parentQuery = new QueryRequest(url);
                //projQuery.setFetch(new Fetch("_ref", "_refObjectUUID", "_refObjectName"));
                QueryResponse parentResponse = restApi.query(parentQuery);

                if (parentResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println ("proj Response... " + parentResponse.toString());

                    JsonArray projParent = parentResponse.getResults();
                    tempHierarchy.concat(projParent.get(0).getAsString());
                    JsonArray tempParent = parentResponse.getResults();
                    proj = tempParent.getAsJsonObject();
                } else {
                    moreParents = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("The following errors occurred: ");
            for (String err : projResponse.getErrors()) {
                System.err.println("\t" + err);
            }
            throw new java.lang.Error("Rally API Call Error Occurred");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a GetRequest instead of a QueryRequest since you're just reading a single object.  Also, include Parent in your fetch.  Then you should have the data to be able to determine whether there is a parent and to continue looping or not.

Comment: I will give this a try and post an update.  Thank you.

Comment: This WORKED !! <br/> <code> GetRequest projRequest = new GetRequest("/project/" + parentUUID); </code> <br/> . I iteratated over the above GetRequest until no more parent projects.  Thanks !